# Why I don't have there NotSerializableException?

Tags: java, serializable, externalizable

Why I don't have there `NotSerializableException` cause in class `A` that is serialized I have `private B b` that is not serialized and I know that if class implement `Serializable` all composite classes have to implement `Serializable`/`Externalizable` as well.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream("a.dat");
        ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutput);
        outputStream.writeObject(new A());
        fileOutput.close();
        outputStream.close();
    }
}

class A implements Serializable
{
    private int age;
    private B b;
}

class B
{

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you serialise `new A()`, `b` is `null` so no `B`.

It is the runtime type that is important - for instance you could have `class BDerived extends B implements java.ui.Serializable`. Or an `ArrayList` could be serialised from `List` field reference.

You can see the exception if you initialise `b` with a non-`null`, non-serialisable type. For instance

```
    private B b = new B();
```